# Jquery not selecting proper href's

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, href

This script:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ("a:not(http://)") {
            $(this).attr('href', '/' + href);
        }
    });
});
```

Add the slash to every link even links with the contain "http://" Not sure why? I do not get any errors?

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: What are you expecting `if("a:not(http://)")` to do?

Comment: Why are you doing this? This will be updating relative links, SSL links, file links, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mixed up two things:

- jQuery selectors:

  ```
  $(function() {
      $('a:not([href^="http://"])').each(function() {
          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          $(this).attr('href', '/' + href);  
      });
  });
  ```
- and pure javascript `if` statements:

  ```
  $('a').each(function() {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     if (href.substr(0, 'http://'.length) == 'http://'){
         $(this).attr('href', '/' + href); 
     }   
  });
  ```

Both do the same.

Note that they will generate invalid links for other schemes than http (e.g. `/https://example.com/index.html`). Depending on how clean the HTML code you're working with is, you may simply look for the colon to identify absolute links:

```
$(function() {
    $('a:not([href*=":"])').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href', '/' + href);  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you code is equal to the following

```
$(function() {
   $('a').each(function() {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      if(true) { $(this).attr('href', '/' + href); }   
   });
});
```

if you really want to update href based on condition, if statetment should be different:

```
$(function() {
   $('a').each(function() {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     if(href.indexOf('http://') == -1 ) { $(this).attr('href', '/' + href); }   
   });
});
```

Another way would be the one offered by @Yogu, where you simple don't loop for links which you are not going to update

Answer (score 0):

Just a addon to Yogu,

Remember that your in the context of each  tag. "Inside the  object itself".
So, you can access the href directly.

```
$('a').each(function() {
   if (this.href.substr(0, 'http://'.length) == 'http://'){
       this.setAttribute('href', '/' + href); 
   }   
});
```